# How to handle type-erasure when dealing with Scalatest's Prettifier

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest, type-erasure

I encountered the following problem when writing unit tests for my Scala application:

For my unit-tests I don't want to see the whole object in the output (in case of a failing test) because I only care about the `id`. That's why I am using a `org.scalactic.Prettifier` like this:

```scala
case class Node(n: id, doesntMatterString: String)

implicit val prettifier: Prettifier = Prettifier(
  {
    case n: Node=> "n" + n.id
    case ns: Seq[Node] => ns.map("n" + _.id).mkString(",")
  }
)
```

Some tests may output one single `Node` while some others may output a `Seq[Node]`.

While this generally works I still get the following warning:

`non-variable type argument Node in type pattern Seq[Node] (the underlying of Seq[Node]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`

I know that type erasure is the problem here, but cannot figure out how to write my `Prettifier` in a way so that this warning won't be displayed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying just to avoid the warning (in which case `@unchecked` will work), or also to avoid class cast exceptions in the case of something like `Seq(1, 2).pretty`?

Comment: Both I would say. But I think I can avoid class cast exceptions by adding sth like `case _ => "unknown" even though I would prefer to run into the class cast excpetion in that case I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use recursive pattern matching.

Here's an example (without a `Prettifier`):

```scala
case class Id(id: String)
case class Node(n: Id, s: String)

def prettifyRec(a : Any): String = a match {
   case Node(n, _) => "n" + n.id
   case ((n: Node) :: Nil) => prettifyRec(n)
   case ((n: Node) :: (tail: Seq[_])) => prettifyRec(n) + "," + prettifyRec(tail)
   case _ => "ERR"
}

println(prettifyRec(Seq(Node(Id("e"), "i"))))
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/xapRIcD/1)

Comment: I'm still getting this warning: `non-variable type argument Node in type pattern Seq[Node] (the underlying of Seq[Node]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]     case (n: Node) :: (tail: Seq[Node]) => prettifyRec(n) + "," + prettifyRec(tail)`

Comment: @FlorianBaierl oh of course, just replace `Seq[Node]` with `Seq[_]`.